# RAID 5 array mdadm add command no response

Tags: raid, mdadm

On ubuntu server, I have a software RAID 5 array, four 2TB drives. One of the drives died, I sent it in and got a replacement. I put the replacement in my server, used an sfdisk command to set the partition table to the same as the other drives. I then tried to add this new drive to the array using the command:

```
sudo mdadm --manage /dev/md127 --add /dev/sdd1
```

Where md127 is the array name and sdd1 is the only partition on the new hard drive. However, when running this command, there is no response. I check /proc/mdstat to see if the array is resyncing and it does not seem to be doing anything. What am I doing wrong?